# Is it possible to add a javascript variable into a JQuery .css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this javascript function with a loop in it

```
function blackOut() {
'use strict';
for (i = 100; i > 0; i = i - 1) {
    $("body").css();
    }
}
```

I want to add this css code using the JQuery function .css()

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(i);
filter: brightness(i);
```

Such that the screen will blackout.

What do I write inside the .css() that will allow me to have the variable 'i' inside as well?

Comment: Try using animate instead meaning the jquery animate functions that allow you to change css values over a given time period. It was kind of designed for this purpose. Look at the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

This should make the trick:

```
function blackOut() {
'use strict';
$body = $("body");
for (i = 100; i > 0; i = i - 1) {
    $body.css('-webkit-filter', 'brightness('+ i +')');
    $body.css('filter', 'brightness('+ i +')');
    }
}
```